# Nested antd tables not renderring antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to render a nested table inside a table in antd,the issue is that the rows are not being displayed, there is the proper space between rows but for some reason I am not able to see the data.

the way I am doing it is on my parent table on the property 'expandedRowRender':

```
<Table
          rowKey="uuid"
          columns={this.getColumns()}
          data={data}
         expandedRowRender={record => this.expandedRowRender(record.children)}
/>
```

columns on my parent table are:

```
getColumns() {
    const columns = [
      {
        title: translate('name'),
        dataIndex: 'name',
      },
      {
        title: translate('type'),
        width: '30%',
        dataIndex: 'docType',
        render: (val, rec) => {
          return rec.parent
            ? `${translate('subcategory')} (${rec.parent[0].name})`
            : translate('category')
        },
      },
    ]

    columns[0] = this.addSearchFilter({
      column: columns[0],
      key: 'name',
      type: 'search',
      refreshKey: 'categories',
    })

    return columns
  }
```

and the table that is nested and should be displaying:

```
expandedRowRender = row => {
   
    const columnas = [
      {
        title: translate('name'),
        key: 'name',
        render: val => {
          return <div>{val.name}</div>
        },
      },
      {
        title: translate('docType'),
        key: 'docType',
        render: (val, rec) => {
          return (
            <div>
             {rec.data},
            </div>
          )
        },
      },
    ]

    return (
      <Table
        columns={columnas}
        dataSource={row}
        rowKey={row.uuid}
      />
    )
  }
```

I have been browsing around but I couldnt find any help on this, there was sth about the unique keys on rows but I am already pointing at the keys on both tables

**UPDATE**

I found the problem, apparently is a matter of specifying the key to the nested table:

```
<Table
       columns={columns}
          dataSource={row}
          pagination={false}
          rowKey={record => record.uuid}
          key="a"
/>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this bug in a codepen?

Comment: Hi Jay, I found my way out of here, Iupdated the question, but thanks a lot for the interest in helping

Comment: Then put that update in an answer

Comment: I did, is at the bottom

Comment: No, you didn't. You just edited your question. The answer goes into the textbox at the bottom of the page. Put your answer there, Click "Post your answer" and "Accept" the answer by clicking the check icon beside it

Comment: got you, now is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER**

I found the problem, apparently is a matter of specifying the key to the nested table:

```
<Table
       columns={columns}
          dataSource={row}
          pagination={false}
          rowKey={record => record.uuid}
          key="a"
/>
```